# What's the meaning of "little twist" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I couldn't understand the meaning of "little twist" in this sentence:

> Prime Wardrobe offers a **little twist**, however: The more you keep...

Complete Sentence:

> Amazon today launched Prime Wardrobe, a service like Trunk Club and other online retailers that lets you order clothes and return them free if they don’t live up to your expectations. Prime Wardrobe offers a **little twist**, however: The more you keep, the more you save. Keep four items in your box and get 10 percent off. Save five or more and receive 20 percent off. Boxes are resealable and come with a shipping label.

[Link: Original text.](https://venturebeat.com/2017/06/20/amazon-launches-prime-wardrobe-to-eat-the-fashion-industry/amp/)

All the meanings that I've found for the word "twist" sound weird in the context of this sentence. What is the correct meaning of "little twist" here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the expression "With a twist" means?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194524/what-does-the-expression-with-a-twist-means)

Answer (score 27):

I think it means a feature that makes Prime Wardrobe different from other, similar online retailers that also allow for free returns.  It seems to follow this definition of **twist** from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist):

> a variant approach or method :  gimmick

Answer (score 10):

Think of it as a play on *[plot twist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plot_twist)*:

> An unexpected development in a book, film, television programme, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *straight forward* as you would expect from the initial description (*A service like X, that lets you do Y*), but does have an unexpected turn - a *Little Twist*

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).